# Problema Git, definir default identity

Tags: git

Estoy intentando subir un repositorio desde mi portátil al github, pero mi terminal luego de darle los comandos `git init   git add .`  y `git commit -m " "` me arroja la respuesta

```
Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

> Soy una estudiante y tengo 50 años, me entusiasma esto por eso hago un curso de programación y aún no sé mucho. ¿Podrían por favor darme una explicación sencilla de qué hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Git necesita que establezcas algunas configuraciones antes.

Debes establecer un email y un nombre para mostrar ejecutando los siguientes comandos desde la consola:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Ambos tienen unos valores de ejemplo que debes reemplazar por los tuyos.

El email debería ser el que usaste para registrarte en Github o uno que te asignar Github del estilo
`USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com`

Comment: En realidad no hay restricción con respecto a cual debe ser el correo. Podría ser cualquier correo con el que quieras que los commits sean asociados y no tiene que ser específicamente con el que te registraste en github o gitlab.

Comment: @eftshift0 claro, es una sugerencia que  da [Github](https://docs.github.com/es/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address)

Comment: muchisismas gracias, me resulto de gran ayuda ,tu solucion.